# Refresh jQuery DataTable with ajax.reload() AND send data to server

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using `jQuery DataTables` and I set up a button that, if clicked, triggers a refresh of the entire table. 
Normally, that would be accomplished by writing the following:

```
"buttons": [
  {
    "text": "<span class='some-icon-class'></span>Refresh",
    "className": "some-button-class",
    "action": function (e, dt, node, config) {
      dt.ajax.reload();
    }
  }
]
```

However, in order for the data to be correctly fetched from the server, I need to send a parametre. For example, the table initialization is performed as follows:

```
serverSide: false,
processing: true,
ajax: {
  url: "/path/to/file.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    "parametre": parametreName
  }
}
```

So, is there a way to send a parametre with `ajax.reload()`? If not, how would I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fnServerParams key to set your params.

```
"fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
  aoData.push(); // You can push your params here
}
```

Then you can set

```
"fnServerData": datatable2Rest // Your custom function that does the ajax call
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. I do not have a function performing the ajax call, since I am using the built-in option in the DataTable constructor.

Comment: You would need to use server params or else in case of a GET request you can append in query string of the url. So make your url responsible for setting the params

Comment: I tried both with `fnServerParams` and by performing a GET request, but no avail. `dt.ajax.reload()` always uses the old parameter which was sent the first time when the table was initialized.